# Conv2D for words Embeddings using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm working on text classification research on Keras. I used W2V to represent my vocabulary.

First, I create an input layer:

```python
input_layer= Input(shape (windows_size, ), dtype='int32', name='word_input')
```

Second, load the pre-trained embeddings:

```python
embd = Embedding(embeddings.shape[0],
                 embeddings.shape[1],
                 input_length=input_len,
                 weights=[embeddings],
                 trainable=False,
                 name='word_embed')(input_layer)
```

Third, I apply Conv1D

```python
conv_net  =Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, activation='relu')(embd)
```

For Conv1D, it works perfectly. But, now I want to use two kinds of embeddings to represent the input text, e.g. w2v and glove. Then, my input text will have a **3 dimension**, i.e. the input sentence can be seen as an image with a width of 3, a height of 1 and depth of 2 ( the two embeddings).

I tried to create one input layer

```python
input_layer= Input(shape (windows_size, ), dtype='int32', name='word_input')
```

My question is: how to create an embedding for two types of embeddings?

```python
    embd = Embedding(embeddings.shape[0], # embeddings width
                     embeddings.shape[1], # embeddings length
                     input_length=input_len,                         
                     weights=[embB_W2V, embd_GloVe], # Here I want to pass two embedding array. One for Glove and one for W2v
                     trainable=False,
                     name='word_embed')(input_layer)
```

conv_net = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(embed_layer_ft)

but it did not work as the weights=[embB_W2V, embd_GloVe] size miss-matches with the embeddings

Comment: What output do you expect from this `Embedding` layer (I mean shape)

Comment: In case of Conv1D, the embeddings size is: (emb_ft.shape[0], emb_ft.shape[1], input_length). But, for Conv2D, I'm expecting to have (emb_ft.shape[0], emb_ft.shape[1], input_length, 2), where the 2 is the two embeddings that we have (W2V, GloVe). It would be like an image with 2 channales. (#number of images, #width, #height, #channels)

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 layers of embeddings and merge them.

Answer (score 0):

I might set up 2 inputs and concatenate them. Something like:

```
initial_embeddings = np.concatenate((emb1array, emb2array), axis=1)
in1 = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH,), dtype='int32', name='input1')
in2 = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH,), dtype='int32', name='input2')
input_layer = concatenate([in1, in2])
embed_layer = Embedding(output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM,
                    input_dim=VOCABULARY_SIZE, 
                    input_length=MAX_LENGTH,                     
                    weights=[initial_embeddings],
                    trainable=True)(input_layer)
```

you could also just concatenate the inputs before defining the keras model instead of within keras.

if you train your embeddings on the input corpus (trainable=True), initializing with 2 3rd-party embeddings doesn't sound like best practice. If you set trainable=False, combining 2 pre-trained embedding matrices trained on different subject matter might make sense in some situations.